# How to get serve url without AppEngine for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have Google Cloud Storage set up, is there is a way to get serve url without Google App Engine?

I don't want to use Google App Engine, I want to use Spring Framework instead. Is there is a library by google to do that without using App Engine SDK?

Comment: Do you just want a Java library to access Google Cloud Storage, like https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage ?

Comment: @coryan no, I want to generate url which can be used by UI like this one https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make individual objects or whole buckets in Cloud Storage to be made public.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) is how.

If keeping data private is needed (like having a Bucket Privacy Only enabled), using signed URLs will do the trick. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) is how.
An easy way to create signed URLs is with gsutil’s signurl command. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl) is how.

Note that signed URLs are by default valid for 1 hour, but the duration can be changed with the -d option. Since the maximum value is 7 days, periodically generating new signed URLs might be required. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl#options).

*EDIT

Signed URL can be used outside of App Engine. You can find some details about the method that does this [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/blob/2aa9d803ed532d91a5f430368f1ec4fd21f3dd24/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-storage/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/storage/Blob.java#L747).
It uses this class declaration, independently of App Engine:

```
public URL signUrl(long duration, TimeUnit unit, SignUrlOption... options);
```

You can find a usage of the method in a simple Python code, which might help you [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1295#issuecomment-381181305).

With that said, I suggest you take a look at [Imgix](https://www.imgix.com/), as it supports GCS buckets as object sources and perform the same kind of operations. Info [here](https://docs.imgix.com/setup/creating-sources/google-cloud-storage).

Comment: Thank you so much. But Is there is a way to get urls like in this article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556 but without App Engine?

Comment: Please view edits to my answer, with additional info that should help.

Comment: Thank you, it is not exactly what I was looking for, as I was looking for google solution for this one, without any extra services, but it still helps, so thank you.

Comment: Signed URL is indeed a function provided by Google, through a Google Cloud Client Library’s Cloud API. APIs can be used independently and will most likely work with the proper Spring Framework configuration.
I think you will find this documentation quite helpful to understanding Client Libraries: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained

Comment: Here is information about the installation and reference for all Google Cloud Client Libraries, just select the one relevant to your language of preference: 
https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries

One very easy method of creating a signed url is with your terminal, using gsutil. 
Here is how: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/signurl.

I hope this was the answer you were looking for.